# MySQL Explain plain doesn't show index used when it should be

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I'm trying to run a query in MySQL that's timing out after a couple of minutes on a QA system with 8 million+ rows. It runs fine for me locally, but obviously less data.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
    system_name as systemName, 
    systemLabel,  
    feature_vector as featureVector, 
    code as norcaCode,
    count(1) as sum 
    FROM (
        SELECT a.id, 
        a.object_id, 
        a.system_name, 
        d.label as systemLabel, 
        b.norca_type AS norcaType, 
        b.feature_vector, 
        a.seqnb, 
        a.object_index, 
        c.code 
    FROM 
        system_objectdata a  
    JOIN 
        sick_il_dacq.system_barcode_norca  b 
    ON 
        a.id = b.system_objectdata_id  
    AND 
        a.partition_key  = b.partition_key  
    LEFT JOIN 
        system_feature_vector c  
    ON 
        b.feature_vector = c.value 
    JOIN 
        sick_il_services.system_config d  
    ON 
        a.system_name = d.name  

    WHERE LEFT(FROM_UNIXTIME(object_scan_time/1000),10) >= SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, 100) 
    AND 
        norca_type = 'BARCODE' 
     AND 
        a.is_duplicate = 0 

    ) detail 
    
    GROUP BY 
        system_name, feature_vector, norcaCode;
```

Here's the explain plan:
[image]

It looks like the link to table d, system_config, is has no possible keys.
However, there is an index for name on the table:

[image]

Any idea why it's not using the name index? And in general, any ideas on how to improve the query speed?

Comment: If I ask you to look up all people whose first name is "Jack" in a telephone book, can you do it efficiently?

Comment: The name is unique.

Comment: In addition, the name is indexed as unique, with a type of BTREE. So a search based on the name should be extremely efficient, if MySQL would use it. But for some reason, according to the explain, it's not. So, the query is scanning all systems for each of the 8 million rows. That's the problem.

Comment: But the telephone book isn't sorted by first name. So you have to read the whole book cover to cover to find the entry with the _first_ name of Jack. The book is sorted by last name, then by first name. This matches your case because `name` is the second column of the index, and you aren't searching by `facility_id` first, as far as I see.

Comment: Ah, right. Makes sense. I will try it out.

Comment: When posting query-optimization questions, you really should start by showing the full table definitions. That is, use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` and that will output the table definition. Don't give partial information and [don't use screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: You might like my presentation "[How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really)" or the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Comment: Great and thanks.  I plan to go through both your presentation and the video, as they are exactly what I need.   I do have another question - the explain plan now shows the UK_system_config in the possible_keys, but the "key" column itself still shows as NULL. Does that mean it still won't use the key?

Comment: Yes, if `key` shows NULL, then it is not using an index for this query. The optimizer may have decided it was more costly to use the index than to simply read the table, based on how frequently the condition is met. I have found that if you are searching for a value that is matched by about 20% or more of the index entries, then the optimizer skips using the index. That's not an official documented threshold, just an observation of mine.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. There are 150+ systems to choose from, so in this case it should be using it. I'm going to add the facility as part of the join anyway, just in case there is a situation in the wild where it gets used. Another question, if I may - is there a query analyzer you could recommend? Unfortunately, the MySQL version we're on is 5.37, so "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" is not available. I've already tried "datadog", but it's not running on my PC, probably due to company restrictions or PC limitations.

Comment: I use EXPLAIN: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html